# unity + Vuforia balck screen in android AR app

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

i built an AR project using Unity 2022.3.22f1 and Vuforia 10.22, the app is working just fine in the my pc using webcam but after building it and Install it in my Samsung A21S (that have android 12) the camera permission pop up after allows it the app gose black screen any help please

i've tried many tricks that I found in the internet but still not working